# can I deploy static files on firebase and node js server on heroku

Tags: node.js, express, web-deployment, web-development-server

### I want to deploy static file on firebase and node js server on Heroku. Is it possible to request to the server with static HTML which is deployed on firebase and server deployed on Heroku

**I have some issues with that**

1. 1.Can I use that server which deploys on Heroku by firebase to send a request to the server
2. 2.Can post some type of data by static files in firebase to the server to process some functionality
3. I did deploys on both firebase and Heroku but during the request in the console showing cors blocked
4. After some research I use **cors module in node** but still, I'm not
   getting required output

**This is my code on server-side**

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const cors = require('cors')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
const app = express()
const corsOptions = {
origin: 'https://https://sample-377b8.web.app',
optionsSuccessStatus: 200 ,// For legacy browser support
 methods: "GET, PUT"
}
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')))
app.use(express.json({limit:'1mb'}))
let data;
//my routes
app.post('/',cors(corsOptions),(req,res)=>{
data = req.body
console.log(data)
res.send({
"success":"200 response",
"res":"You are now just talked with server" 
})
})
 app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))
```

**This on firebase static html file**

```
 let data = {lat,lon}
        await fetch('https://demoserver-app.herokuapp.com/',{mode:"no-cors"},{
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
 headers: {
' Content-Type': 'application/json',},
 body: JSON.stringify(data),
       }).then( async (dat) =>{
           const res = await dat.json()
           document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = res.success
           document.getElementById('anotherres').innerHTML = res.res
           
       })
   })
```

**Code is working perfectly on Heroku deployed static file**
same code which on static file which is deployed on Heroku worked finely but it does send any response to other firebase deployed static file

****This is a link for deployed website on firebase and Heroku** **
https://demoserver-app.herokuapp.com
https://sample-377b8.web.app/
**Please help me with this problem**

Comment: "origin: 'https://https://sample-377b8.web.app'," why there are two https ?

Comment: Because I deployed a static website on firebase and node js server on Heroku

Comment: no I mean there are two https in your url '1)https:2)//https:-- //sample-377b8.web.app',

Comment: ok, I just copy two times sorry. Apart from that code is ok or not?